# Powershell create SQL table with column names from data in another table

Tags: powershell

I have a table called 'Prices' with the column 'Fruit'. This 'Fruit' column contains loads of duplicated fruit i.e. Banana Apple Pear Banana Apple Grape

I want to create a new table, with the column headings as unique fruit names from the table above. So the new table (called 'Weight') using the example above would look like:

|Banana|Apple|Pear|Grape|

How do I do this using the SqlServer PowerShell module?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLPS module notwithstanding...

Select-Object -unique to only collect unique items in the table, then create your new table as you normally would.

```
# Get parameters, examples, full and Online help for a cmdlet or function

(Get-Command -Name Select-Object).Parameters
Get-help -Name Select-Object -Examples
Get-help -Name Select-Object -Full
Get-help -Name Select-Object -Online

Example 5: Select unique characters from an array

"a","b","c","a","a","a" | Select-Object -Unique

a
b
c
```

and SQL natively has...

> The DISTINCT keyword eliminates duplicate rows from the results of a
> SELECT statement. If DISTINCT is not specified, all rows are returned,
> including duplicates.
>
> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187831%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396